# I'm trying to create a 2D dynamic array where the width of the array is different from the height

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I've been looking everywhere and I can't seem to find the correct syntax. This is what I have thus far.

```
int width;
int height;
int maxgrey;
int **dimensions;

//...read in height and width from file


dimensions = new int *[ width ][ height ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int width;
int height;
int **dimensions;

//...

dimensions = new int *[height];

for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ ) dimensions[i] = new int[width];
```